# azure pipeline is not refreshing my webapp

Tags: azure, web-applications, azure-pipelines

I set up an azure pipeline that runs a webapp. When I update the source repos, the pipeline refeshes, but the webapp does not.

Any suggestions of what might be the issue?

Here is the associated yaml file:

```
# Docker
# Build and push an image to Azure Container Registry
# https://docs.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/docker

trigger:
- main

resources:
- repo: self

variables:
  # Container registry service connection established during pipeline creation
  dockerRegistryServiceConnection: 'blah1'
  imageRepository: 'blah2'
  containerRegistry: 'blah3.azurecr.io'
  dockerfilePath: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/Dockerfile'
  tag: '$(Build.BuildId)'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
- stage: Build
  displayName: Build and push stage
  jobs:
  - job: Build
    displayName: Build
    pool:
      vmImage: $(vmImageName)
    steps:
    - task: Docker@2
      displayName: Build and push an image to container registry
      inputs:
        command: buildAndPush
        repository: $(imageRepository)
        dockerfile: $(dockerfilePath)
        containerRegistry: $(dockerRegistryServiceConnection)
        tags: |
          $(tag)
```

Comment: Where are you updating your web app to point to the new container version?

Comment: code comes from azure repos

Comment: That didn't answer my question. If your app service is running a container, somewhere, at some point, you told it *which* container to run, including a tag. You're creating a new container with a new tag on it. Somehow, somewhere, you have to update your app service to run the *new* tag. You're not including any evidence that you're doing that.

Answer (score -1):

you need 2 pipelines ones a build pipeline which builds the files to publish, the next is a release pipeline which deploys to the files to the actual function. You also have to either trigger them manually or set the triggers.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_cOckpopDkY&t=716s

Comment: sorry you don't need to physical pipelines but conceptual you do